# How to grep with a list of words

Tags: grep

I have a file A with 100 words in it separated by new lines. I would like to search file B to see if ANY of the words in file A occur in it.

I tried the following but does not work to me:

```
grep -F A B
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You need to use the option `-f`:

```
$ grep -f A B
```

The option `-F` does a fixed string search where as `-f` is for specifying a file of patterns. You may want both if the file only contains fixed strings and not regexps.

```
$ grep -Ff A B
```

You may also want the `-w` option for matching whole words only:

```
$ grep -wFf A B
```

Read `man grep` for a description of all the possible arguments and what they do.

Comment: Is -F just an optimization if you don't want to use regexps?

Comment: What about finding all occurrences of words in file A in a *directory tree B*, listing only the filenames of all matches in B?

Comment: @zealoushacker -H to also print the filename.

Answer (score 4):

To find a very long list of words in big files, it can be more efficient to use egrep:

```bash
# remove the last \n of A
$ tr '\n' '|' < A > A_regex
$ egrep -f A_regex B
```